# How does Lex/Flex match multiple user defined regex

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer

I am new to the compiler and I am learning to implement a scanner using the algorithm provided by the Dragon Book (Compiler Principles). I have implemented the algorithm `3.36` that translates a regex directly to a DFA.

As a scanner uses many regexes to define different tokens, I am interested in how Flex deals with the multiple DFAs after translation. A very intuitive thought would be to try every DFA and simulate the DFA. If a token reaches the end state in the DFA then returns the corresponding token identifier.

However, I would also argue that this method is might be more computationally intensive than the regex-to-NFA and then NFA-to-DFA approach even if the trials can be done using concurrent threads. Because in that method one can just combine all the NFAs generated with the $\epsilon$ action from the start state and run the algorithm to form a complete DFA.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Or is flex using the subset construction algorithm in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

It combines all NFAs into a single machine (which is a trivial operation, so much so that it doesn't actually require any code; all flex does is add new rules as transitions from the start state). It then uses the subset construction to reduce the combined NFA to a DFA. The machine so constructed differs from the theoretical DFA in a couple of important ways:

1. Each accepting state is associated with the number of a rule. (In the subset construction, if a state set includes more than one accepting state, then the smallest rule number is used, which means the machine will accept the first matching rule.)
2. When the machine is scanning, each time it passes through an accepting state, it records the number of that state and the offset of the input. When the machine reaches the sink state (that is, the state with no outgoing transitions), then the input is backed up to the recorded offset and the rule number corresponding to the recorded state is returned. (Flex has an optimisation which avoids having to record the information in the case that every state in the DFA is accepting. If you write your patterns carefully, you can activate this optimisation.)

Comment: But then I have a quick follow-up question: why do we need the direct translation algorithm from regex to DFA? Like just for matching a single user input?

Comment: @ccjeff: it's always good to be aware of different ways to solve problems. That's basically the point of CS education.